# How to keep writing in batch file after I execute it

Tags: batch-file

So i'm currently learning how to program using Laravel PHP framework. I noticed that most controllers and classes can be created and there is a high interaction level with the framework by using the php artisan commands.
So I decide to create a little batch script that reads:

```
cd:/xampp/htdocs/project
php artisan make:controller
pause
```

As you can see, the php artisan is missing the controller name.
What I need that this bat does is:

> Open the bat file
>
> execute the cd command to go to the directory (which it is doing)
>
> input the php artisan command
>
> not execute the php artisan and keep waiting for me to finish the
> command with the controller name or else it will crash and give me an error
>
> after I write the controller name, press Enter, execute the php artisan command and create the
> controller.

All I need is for the program to halt and be ready, waiting for my input.

Comment: Your backslashes are forward slashes. Windows tries to accept this but it can cause problems. `Driveletter:\folder\file.ext` or in UNC `\\server\share\folder\file.ext`

Comment: I expand. Your backslashes are forward slashes. Windows tries to accept this but it can cause problems. `Driveletter:\folder\file.ext:streamname` or in UNC `\\server\share\folder\file.ext:streamname`. If streamname not specified it assumes the default unnamed stream. Almost no files have extra streams. The `driveletter:` syntax allows relative paths but UNC does not. Also prepending a path with `\\?\\` turns off filename checking rules but can't be used with relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a batch file to ask for user input like this:

```
set /p input=Enter controller name:
```

And then you can use the result in the rest of the batch file:

```
php artisan make:controller %input%
```

Also, if you don't want to see each command as it's executing, put this at the top of your batch file:

```
@echo off
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helps me